Kernel image (vmlinuz...) on /boot has always the same date/time across different compilations. Where is it specified?
On a Fedora System, I'm often recompiling the kernel in order to add the necessary T2 patches for the kernel to benefit from the full capabilities of my MacBook Pro (and also so that the keyboard works with the apple-bce drivers).
It happens though that, when I recreate the kernel package RPMs using the original SRPM from the Fedora repository, no matter when I compile the kernel, the installed vmlinuz file that goes into /boot has always the same date/time for each release (independent of the compilation date/time).  This happens even for my custom kernel (in which I just stuff the patches inside linux-kernel-test.patch before compiling).
The problem with this is that I endup having multiple vmlinuz... images on /boot with the exact same date/time, which confuses refind (the boot loader I use) on what image to load.
Of course I workaround this by running touch after installing the custom Kernel rpms, but I'd like to know where is this date/time configured.  I could not determine this by doing a quick visual inspection of the .spec file and of the the source code, and I'd really appreciate if a good soul could indicate me the spot and file.
Note: I understand the date is artificially set so that the generated kernels have uniform properties for the same version and patch level, which is good for testing purposes, but this is not clear for me if this artificial date/time is a distribution independent kernel attribute or a Fedora package attribute.

Does the timestamp match the timestamp of the last changelog entry in the .spec?

Yes, in fact it does and yesterday I figured this out.  Adding a new changelog entry allowed me to define a new date.  Thanks.

After digging a lot, in parallel endorsed by Stephen Kitt's comment, I found the Fedora documentation that explains how mtime for the packages are set on the
link below:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ReproducibleBuildsClampMtimes
extracted text:

 Summary
The %clamp_mtime_to_source_date_epoch RPM macro will be set
to 1. When an RPM package is built, mtimes of packaged files will be
clamped to $SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH which is already set to the date of the
latest %changelog entry. As a result, more RPM packages will be
reproducible: The actual modification time of files that are e.g.
modified in the %prep section or built in the %build section will not
be reflected in the resulting RPM packages. Files in RPM packages will
have mtimes that are independent of the time of the actual build.

So, basically the solution to change the mtime of the generated package files is to add a new changelog entry in the %changelog section of the .spec file with a more recent date.  The mtimes of the installed files will be set accordingly.

As a general rule, if you make a change to a package before building it, it’s a good idea to add a changelog entry anyway ;-). (Even if Fedora changelog entries tend to be very terse.)
